# Unable to call JNI exported functions in c# dotnetcore

Tags: .net-core, java-native-interface, dllimport, name-mangling

I have a shared object file (.so) created for Java platform, written in cpp and auto generated from JNI. I want to utilize the same shared object file's exported methods in c# dotnet core as well.
Some methods are accessible via their mangled names and are being called correctly. Rest of the methods either dont have a mangled name attached to them or dont work.

I found out the symbols using nm -D /lib/file name

symbol examples:

```
000000000000c7d9 T Java_java_1shm_1wrapper_SharedMemWrapper_addAgent
000000000000c840 T Java_java_1shm_1wrapper_SharedMemWrapper_addAgent2
000000000000d279 T Java_java_1shm_1wrapper_SharedMemWrapper_addAgentACDAttribute
```

Symbols that are working example c# code:

```
[DllImport("jshmwrap", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "_ZN20StateSvcSharedMemCtl14_initSharedMemEiPKci")]
        public static extern int initSharedMem(String svc_name);
```

Symbol not working:

```
[DllImport("jshmwrap.so", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "_ZN20StateSvcSharedMemCtl15getMessageQueueEPcii13enSMQSyncType")]
        public static extern long getMessageQueue(String q_name, int create);
[DllImport("jshmwrap.so", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int Java_java_1shm_1wrapper_SharedMemWrapper_initSharedMem(String svc_name);
```

What am I missing here? Why do some mangled names work and others do not? Also, why don't exported function names work?